# Change units of curve object types in Draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I know I can select ***View > Units > Millimeters*** in the main menu, but even if I do that, it only seems to impact some of the objects I draw: *circle, square, rectangle*.

Unfortunately, for other type of objects (like *line, curve, arrow, link*) it seems the units for the "Line start" and "Line end" fields remain expressed in points.

Is this normal behavior or am I missing something obvious?

Best regards,

Cristian